# How to use date_trunc in PostgreSQL to truncate to 100 milliseconds?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The `date_trunc` function uses field either millisecond or second, but millisecond is too small for me and second too large. I want something in between like 100 milliseconds (1/10 second).

How can I achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do this with conversion.  The following should give you tenths of a second:

```
select cast(datecol as timestamp(1))
```

Comment: hi @Gordon Linoff thanks for your answer. I want to aggregate according to the 1/10 second. date_trunc can be used as aggregation function, can cast do the job?